# How Existence Of Matter Is Possible Inside The Black Hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, big-bang, singularities, unified-theories

According to **[Chronology of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe)**, origin of the universe initiated as per below sequence:

0. Big bang (at 0 sec) occurs in the black hole (10^-35 m in size, Planck Length) at the center of the galaxy.
1. First Phase - Planck Epoch (From 0 to 10^-43 sec), a unified energy (Singularity) comes out from the black hole.
2. Second Phase - Grand Unification Epoch (From 10^-43 sec to 10^-36 sec), three different types of energies split from one unified energy. In this way a total of four types of forces or energies are formed.
3. Third Phase of Particle Epoch (From 10^-36 sec to 370,000 years), these four types of forces form the particles, atoms and the matter of the universe.

This sequence is perfect and correct. But scientists are not yet able to define the unified energy (Singularity) consisting of all four forces of Planck Epoch, so scientists are not considering this chronology of the universe at all.

While scientifically explaining the black hole it is often said that **“Space-time curves after the event horizon in a black hole. Due to infinite gravity, the density of the matter going into the black hole becomes infinite and after the event horizon, even light does not come out of it.”** In this definition of the black holes, words like event or time, light, gravity, density, matter, imaginary matter of infinite density etc., whose reference is possible only if matter exists.

The main basis of science is atoms or matter, which are formed after inflation in the black hole in the third phase of the Big Bang explosion, the Particle Epoch.

**My question is how matter and related stuff are possible inside the black hole when particles, atoms and matter are formed in the third phase?**

Comment: *Big bang (at 0 sec) occurs in the black hole (10^-35 m in size) at the center of the galaxy* Where does the Wikipedia article say *that*?

Comment: *This sequence is perfect and correct.* You have misunderstood it.

Comment: This site is only for mainstream physics, not personal theories.

Comment: 1/3) Distrust over the invisible does not allow scientists to think out of the box. My intention to ask this question is simply to attract the attention of cosmologists to reconsider the theory that says black holes consist of infinitely dense matter. This erroneous hypothesis has entangled them in many mysteries. Chronology of the origin of the universe has been well described sequentially in age-old Indian spiritual texts. For example, the Higgs field is Causal Body, Antimatter is Cosmic Body, Dark Matter is Subtle Body and Dark Energy is Etheric Body.

Comment: 2/3) In the light of the latest discoveries of modern science and these spiritual texts, I revealed how an infinite universe arises from nothing. Dark matter, dark energy, subatomic particles etc. all have nothing like matter but only the vibrating, rotating, revolving or moving pure energy which are controlled by some non-matter entities. Pure energy is also a kind of non-matter entity. So black hole contains only non-matter entities. What are those non-matter entities, this is just a matter of thinking of ourselves because we are also born from that singularity.

Comment: 3/3) Choice is yours, know all about black holes with me or keep on puzzling ever with science.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the mathematical models used to describe Causal Body, Cosmic Body and Etheric Body? @SatyajitPatidar

Comment: Voting to close since this is now obviously not about mainstream physics.

Comment: @SatyajitPatidar You follow the same mistake as many who see the analogy between physical and spiritual terms. Your mistake is taking modern physics for granted. For example, you refer to the “Higgs field”, but what if it doesn’t exist? For example, see this book by a German theoretical physicist: [The Higgs Fake: How Particle Physicists Fooled the Nobel Committee](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/18674141-the-higgs-fake)

Comment: 1/2) Description of the book itself describes six major problems of particle physics. The Higgs field is everywhere in the universe, Spiritual texts describe it as ‘Anand’ or ‘Bliss’ which is the predominant force of nature responsible for life in inanimate atoms. Scientists are not yet able to find the unified energy consisting of all SN force, WN force and EM force. This unified force is the Bliss (or so called Higgs field) which deals with the emotional energy that cannot be defined by the laws of science, so the black holes remain mysteries for science. Black hole contains only Bliss.

Comment: 2/2 Problem with scientists is that they don’t want to think out of the box despite being puzzled with lots of mysteries in science. I went on a dual path of science and spirituality both and revealed most of the mysteries. Have a look at these slides which show the symmetry of singularity from black hole to present life and computer.
https://www.anarvam.com/slide/Slide98.JPG
https://www.anarvam.com/slide/Slide99.JPG
https://www.anarvam.com/slide/Slide100.JPG
https://www.anarvam.com/slide/Slide101.JPG
https://www.anarvam.com/slide/Slide102.JPG
https://www.anarvam.com/slide/Slide103.JPG

Answer (score 2):

> Big bang occurs in the black hole at the center of the galaxy

You appear to be confusing the [Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang), which is the origin of the whole universe, with [supermassive black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermassive_black_hole) which lie, we believe, at the centre of almost every large galaxy.

There are many millions (possibly billions) of supermassive black holes in the universe, but they all formed long after the Big Bang.